# Twice the product of odd numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m$ and $n$ be odd integers such that $m$ is the sum of two squares and $n$ is the sum of two squares. I am supposed to show that $2mn$ is sum of two odd squares.

First, since $m$ and $n$ are both sums of two squares, I showed that $m=4a+1$ for some integer $a$ and $n=4b+1$ for some integer $b$. Then, $$2mn=2(4a+1)(4b+1)=32ab+8a+8b+2.$$ It is correct to think along the lines of splitting $32ab+8a+8b+2$ into sums of two squares? If it is then would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Hint: $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ad-bc)^2+(ac+bd)^2$ shows you that $mn$ is the product of two squares.  Now you have to handle the $2$ and also show that the squares involved are odd.

Comment: If $2(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=2(ad-bc)^2+2(ac+bd)^2$, then do I have to simplify the right hand side until they become sum of two odd squares?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) shows that $mn$ is also a sum of two squares:
$$mn=a^2+b^2$$
hence (applying Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity again but in a very simple case: $2=1^2+1^2$)
$$2mn=(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2.$$
Since $a^2+b^2$ is moreover odd, $a\pm b$ are odd.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: The two alledged duplicates used the same tool but are definitely not duplicates of the present post.

Comment: A question does not need to be exactly the same to be a dupe, see [abstract duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756/242).  Your answer is a special case of the linked dupes (and *many* others).